# How to use `$cond` to group by for multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to match by borough and group by .
What could be missing in the below code? it gives both low and medium as 0.

Comment: Yes, the syntax looks correct. You may want to post a sample input document with the fields that are used in the query.

Comment: Here is an example using `$group` and `$sum` with `$cond`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311604/agregate-and-sum-by-one-key-and-rest/60311771#60311771

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: { borough: "Bronx" }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$address.zipcode",
                low: { $sum: 1 },
                medium: {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$cuisine", "Bakery"] }, 1, 0]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UV767upMiFB