# Combining two mongo results into one output?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDB, but I am a complete beginner. I have two different queries where I want to combine them both into one output (I'm hoping the answer is a single query)

Query 1:

```
db.fin.aggregate([ 
{ "$match": { "misc.incident_characteristics": { "$not": /Officer Involved Incident/ } } },
{ $group: {
       _id: "NonOfficerInvolved",
       nInjured: { $avg: "$casualties.n_injured" },
       nKilled: { $avg: "$casualties.n_killed" }
    }
}
])
```

Which returns

```
{ "_id" : "NonOfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.5048153043227224, "nKilled" : 0.24339953718948618 }
```

Query 2:

```
db.fin.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { "misc.incident_characteristics": "Officer Involved Incident" } },
{ $group: {
       _id: "OfficerInvolved",
       nInjured: { $avg: "$casualties.n_injured" },
       nKilled: { $avg: "$casualties.n_killed" }
    }
}
])
```

Which returns

```
{ "_id" : "OfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.3599233845980508, "nKilled" : 0.358965692073686 }
```

I would like to get the result of both into one table as seen below. Is it possible to do this in one query?

```
{ "_id" : "NonOfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.5048153043227224, "nKilled" : 0.24339953718948618 } 
{ "_id" : "OfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.3599233845980508, "nKilled" : 0.358965692073686 }
```

Comment: It's call a collection in MongoDB instead of a table.

Comment: Here is a post with similar question and an answer: [Aggregate and sum by one key and rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311604/aggregate-and-sum-by-one-key-and-rest/60311771#60311771).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do that in one query.

Instead of just matching against the magic string, store the match result in a new field as a boolean or string, then group on that new field.

```
db.fin.aggregate([ 
{ "$addFields": { type:{
                $cond:[
                   {$eq:["$misc.incident_characteristics","Officer Involved Incident"]},
                   "OfficerInvolved",
                   "NonOfficerInvolved"
                ]
}}},
{ $group: {
       _id: "$type",
       nInjured: { $avg: "$casualties.n_injured" },
       nKilled: { $avg: "$casualties.n_killed" }
    }
}
])
```

To match using a regular expression, replace the line

```
{$eq:["$misc.incident_characteristics","Officer Involved Incident"]},
```

with

```
{$regexMatch:{
              input:"$misc.incident_characteristics", 
              regex:"Officer Involved Incident" 
              options:"i"
}},
```

Comment: I need one of the queries to include all rows with the keywords "Officer Involved Incident" and the other query needs to include all rows without the keywords "Officer Involved Incident" which is why I was thinking of doing two separate queries.

Comment: The above query is returning `{ "_id" : "OfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.03125, "nKilled" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "NonOfficerInvolved", "nInjured" : 0.4940683093742828, "nKilled" : 0.2523232281082434 }`

Comment: That matches the format you were looking for, right?

Comment: Yes it is the correct format, but it appears this way of querying will add a field value that is always set to false so my values of nInjured and nKilled have changed to incorrect values. I need to mark each row as true/false depending on if it has the keyword "Officer Involved Incident" anywhere in the String for $misc.incident_characteristics. This means that I need to try to use regular expression to mark a row as true or false since I believe it is currently only looking for the specific String "Officer Involved Incident".

Comment: That was how you showed it in the `$match` example.  You can use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#regexmatch-aggregation) instead of `$eq` if needed.  I'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: Well it looks like I messed up again... $misc.incident_characteristics is actually an array of Strings instead of a single String. Sorry to complicate things. I would probably have to somehow iterate through all the Strings in the array.

Comment: In that case you could either use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation) to iterate the array and return a boolean, or use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html)